# Как поднять версию php до 5.3.10 в Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: nginx, php, ubuntu

Установил nginx + php5-fpm версия php получилось 5.3.2. Собственно вопрос как поднять версию php до  5.3.10 или выше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить репозиторий, и установить, например вот [так](http://www.modernfidelity.co.uk/tech/ubuntu-php-535-1004-lts)

Answer (score 0):

Можно скачать исходники и скомпилировать.